# Replacing String Inside Variable Text Value in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns `meta_value` and `meta_key`. Within the values the meta_key column has value `"_sku"`. Sample `_sku` meta_values would be:

- 123 Acming
- 111-23 Acming, Ltd
- 7781 Tesla Company
- 8210-T-Ze Acming, LLC

The first values (before the space) are part numbers, the value after the first space is the manufacturer name.
I am needing to replace any value that has Acming in it with the first 5 characters of the manufacturer's name. In the Acming case this would be "Acmin".

I have tried:

```
UPDATE `rdepot_postmeta`
SET meta_value= REPLACE(meta_value, '%Acming%', 'Acmin')
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%Acming%' AND meta_key = '_sku';
```

When running the query no rows are matched even though there are definitely values with Acming in it.

Comment: Remove the % wildcard characters from your `REPLACE()` parameter, wildcards are not supported in `REPLACE` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrLumie pointed out - Replace() cannot use wild cards.
The working query is:

```
UPDATE `rdepot_postmeta`
SET meta_value= REPLACE(meta_value, 'Acming', 'Acmin')
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%Acming%' AND meta_key = '_sku';
```

This will only update the specified value of _sku's with some variation of Acming in their value.